# How to assign specific technician to solve specific problem in AnyLogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a agent "**customer**" with the parameter "BatteryProblem" randomTrue (0.5), and I have a agent "**Technician**" with population of 3. How can I assign one technique to solve only "BatteryProblem" and the other two techniques to solve the remaining problems that are not battery related?

My model details are given below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable inside `technician` agent called `problemsSolved` of type String. In the main agent, on startup, manually assign what each technician does. Like `technicians(0).problemsSolved = "battery"`.

You can use the "custom resource choice" setting.

Then the incoming agent can choose to only seize resources where `unit.problemsSolved.equals("battery")`. Like this;

[image]

Comment: i flow your instructions and end up with this error "problemsSolved cannot be resolved or is not a field. Location: tech/Main/seize - Seize". How can i solve this error?

Comment: are your units in the `technician` resourcePool linked to the `resourcePool` agent?

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand what exactly i have look for?

Comment: inside resource pool, have you selected technician agent in the section `new resource unit`?

Comment: yes i did. Its already done but still giving that error.

Comment: i also add the image of my technician resource pool above in question so you can also take a look.

Comment: If you change the variable to parameter (the `problemsSolved`), it doesn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249071/discussion-between-aqeel-tariq-and-yashar-ahmadov).

Comment: I change parameter to variable but problem is same.